# adding variable numbers in PHP loop counter

Tags: php

I've got a PHP loop and a counter called $total which is set to 0 before the loop. Then once the loop starts I am adding the value of $weight to the loop counter. I originally did it like this:

```
$total=0;
foreach ($weights as $weight){
    $total = $total+$weight;
}
```

But realised that it also works like this:

```
$total=0;
foreach ($weights as $weight){
    $total += $weight;
}
```

Question is which is the correct method or if both are correct which is the better method?

Thanks

Comment: BTW, did you know there is [array_sum](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sum.asp)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, and neither is better, strictly speaking. [They function identically](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php).

That said, some coding styles prefer `+=` because it's easier to read, while others prefer `$x = $x + $y` because it requires more deliberate action to write, makes more obvious what is happening, and reduces the likelihood of a single-character typo.